# Find parents of an element within a certain div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My html code looks like this...

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="tropical">
            <div class="info">
                <div class="desc">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum.......</p>               
                </div>
                <div class="list_of_fruits">
                    <ul class="list">
                        <li class="fruit">Avocado</li>
                        <li class="fruit">Banana</li>
                        <li class="fruit">Watermelon</li>           
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="sub_tropical">
            <div class="info">
                <div class="desc">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum.......</p>               
                </div>
                <div class="list_of_fruits">
                    <ul class="list">
                        <li class="fruit">Apple</li>
                        <li class="fruit">Blackberry</li>           
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to get all the parent divs of `li` with class "fruit" that are within `div` with id=tropical...

I have done this much so far ...

```
$(".fruit").parents().filter("div");
```

but it selects parents of `<li>` within div with id=sub_tropical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to get only `div`s and "not" `ul`s, try this

```
$("#tropical").find(".fruit").parents().filter("div");
```

Answer (score 6):

USe

```
$("#tropical").find(".fruit").parents();
```

`$("#tropical").find(".fruit")` will get the `.fruits` containing in `#tropical` div

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#tropical").find(".fruit").parents();
```